# How to set hover/active pseudo style to element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My jQM app doesn't have input device such as mouse or tap sensor, only arrow keys. So the buttons should first show the active/hover state programmatically, then user can hit enter to confirm the click, where `click` event is triggered.

I've tried

```
$('#radio' + radioIndex).trigger('hover');
```

and

```
$('#radio' + radioIndex).trigger('mouseenter');
```

which didn't work. Do I have to refresh button? How?

From Chrome Developer Tools I can see that what I want is actually pseudo style `:hover` or `:active`. But it doesn't look there is an easy way to toggle them without messing up with jQM CSS.

How can I properly set the button state from the code to active/hover, thus imitating mouse hovering on it?

Comment: This sounds like it would be more appropriate to trigger `focus` and then style that.  It might even already be styled.  What happens when you do trigger `focus`?

Comment: Surprisingly `focus` is showing what it supposed to show - focus frame. But design-wise active/hover was the closest to what I want. I don't understand why `focus` works and others not.